# execute remote command over ssh strange behaviour

Tags: macos, ssh

Following this instruction how to setup access with public key from https://linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/

and wondering what is wrong with:

```
ssh user@example.com "echo `cat ~/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub` >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

when executing it on OS X instead of doing stuff remotly it claims

```
cat: /Users/andi/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does the file "/Users/andi/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub" exist on the system where you're running this command?

Comment: no. it shoulnd't exists here. It is copied to remote madchine. and the first ocmmand should be executed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you're using is incorrect in steps 3 and 4 of the **Uploading Keys** section. These commands have to be executed on your local computer and not on the remote. Step 4 is also clumsily written, it can be simplified to

```
ssh user@example.com "cat ~/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Finally, you can avoid the entire four step guide if you have command `ssh-copy-id` available on your local computer.

```
ssh-copy-id user@example.com
```

This command automatically adds your local `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote computer.